# How to add a dynamic EditText values in ArrayList

Tags: android

I have created 10 EditText dynamically by using loop. Now I want to give value for all the 10 EditText and I want to add those values in ArrayList. For that i have written the following code.

```
req1estimate_value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    estimate_value=s.toString();
                    estimatedModified = new ArrayList<String>();
                    estimatedModified.add(estimate_value);
                }
            });
                 for(int k=0;k<estimatedModified.size();k++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(estimatedModified.get(k));

                    }
```

But I can only get the value for last EditText. How can i solve this problem? Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are constructing arraylist in `afterTextChanged` method so previous values are cleared each time text changes.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi Thanks! I understood. May i know what is the solution for that?

Comment: Check programmer answer.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting to my answer Misagh:)

Comment: @user3663600 Check my answer below. Please accept the answer if it resolve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
initialize the arraylist after class declaration , because each time you change edittext values your arraylist is getting created in afterTextChanged() method which means if you change the edittext value it is adding to arraylist next time you are changing the edittext value the  empty/new arraylist is creating and adding changed value to it and the cycle goes on upto 10 times so finally you are getting value for last EditText.

```
e.g. 
public class ABC
{

ArrayList<String> estimatedModified = new ArrayList<String>();

req1estimate_value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    estimate_value=s.toString();
                    estimatedModified.add(estimate_value);
                }
            });
                 for(int k=0;k<estimatedModified.size();k++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(estimatedModified.get(k));

                    }
```

Hope this help you. If you have any problems in understanding please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! But if i give 25800 is a value for an EditText then am getting 2,25,258,2580,25800.

Answer (score 0):

you can set loop on parent of added editText children and check if it is editText get it's text and add to array:

```
for(int i=0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
    if(parent.getChildAt(i) InstanceOf EditText){
         EditText et = (EditText) parent.getChildAt(i);
         array.add(et.getText().toString());
    }
}
```